# Convert "MM/yy" to datetime c#

Tags: c#, datetime, date-parsing

I'm storing DateTime value like this - "MM/yy" format (credit card info) **02/30**

but when I retrieve it from DB I need to convert this as a DateTime value.is there any proper way of doing this?

Comment: What are the **business rules** for the conversion?

Comment: also... when was your last PCI compliance audit, just out of curiosity?

Comment: I know someone going to ask this as well :).
I'm not saving that on my end. save these details on ERP partners side. I asked for this solution because if I can do it this way, then it's easier than changing a bunch of codes.
hope you got my pont?

Comment: How about you store it in the DB in `date` type in the first place

Answer (score 0):

try this. Replace this line `dateString = "5/01" + "/ 0001";` to `dateString = yourDate.ToString() + "/ 0001";` .
Because you do not have the year, you must use the month and day when using it.

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string dateString;
DateTime dateValue;

//Use custom formats with M and MM.
dateString = "5/01" + "/0001";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy", enUS,
                                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
```

Comment: The OP does have month and year, just no day - but still a 01 could be used there

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;

...


// Your input value
string ccexp = "02/30";

// Clone the invariant culture and give it a new calendar
CultureInfo customCulture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
customCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = (Calendar) customCulture.Calendar.Clone();

// Set the value such that all two-digit years are in the range 2000-2099
customCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;

// Parse the string to a DateTime
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(ccexp, "MM/yy", customCulture);

// Adjust to very end of month (implied by CC expiration)
dt = dt.AddMonths(1).AddTicks(-1);
        
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("o")); //=> 2030-02-28T23:59:59.9999999
```

[Working .NET Fiddle here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3i3yMQ)

The above assumes you are planning to compare the result using the inclusive operator `<=`.

Depending on your business logic, it may be more efficient to use the *exclusive* operator `<`, in which case you would add a month but *not* subtract a tick.